# Parsing XML in Python: Typeerror: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to parse xml in python but I keep on getting this error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable on line 10 "print("Date:", tree.find('date').text())"

My code is as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = '''<person>
<date>Wednesday, Oct 14 2020 1:03AM</date>
<email hide="yes" />
<username>John Doe</username>
</person>'''


tree = ET.fromstring(data)
print("Date:", tree.find('date').text())
print("Email attr:", tree.find('email').get('hide'))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: date is of type xml.etree.ElementTree.Element and text is an attribute , not a function. Hence the error not callable. date.text will work instead of date.text()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `()` after the `.text`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = '''<person>
<date>Wednesday, Oct 14 2020 1:03AM</date>
<email hide="yes" />
<username>John Doe</username>
</person>'''


tree = ET.fromstring(data)
print("Date:", tree.find('date').text)  # <-- only `.text`
print("Email attr:", tree.find('email').get('hide'))
```

Prints:

```
Date: Wednesday, Oct 14 2020 1:03AM
Email attr: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `()` after `.text` because this is an attribute not method:

```
print("Date:", tree.find('date').text)
print("Email attr:", tree.find('email').get('hide'))
```